# Making list of all combinations from the dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, combinations, python-itertools

I have a dictionary which is received from JSON file with this structure:

```
{
    "First dish": {
        "Soup": {
            "Cabbage": 100,
            "Basis": {
                "Meat": 100,
                "Fish": 80
            }
        },
        "Salad": {
            "Main ingredients": {
                 "Tomato": 150,
                 "Сucumber": 100
            }
        }
    },
    "Wine": 150
}
```

The dish consists of wine and soup or salad. I want to receive the list of all combinations of different sets of ingredients from the dictionary:

```
[[{'Cabbage': 100}, {'Meat': 80}, {'Wine': 150}],
[{'Tomato': 100}, {'Wine': 150}],
[{'Cabbage': 100}, {'Fish': 80}, {'Wine': 150}],
[{'Сucumber': 100}, {'Wine': 150}]]
```

How could it be done on Python?

Comment: This seems like a very odd data structure/problem. I see salad w/ tomato & parsley is valid. Is soup with meat and fish also valid? What about soup with just tomato and soup with just parsley?

Comment: Sorry, that should be combined not parse. But that's not the problem.

Comment: I restated the question in a clearer form. I am sure there is an elegant and simple solution for this. Please reopen it.

Comment: how do you define an ingreditent, a key:value pair where value is a number? but how did you get `{'Meat': 80}` and `{'Tomato': 100}` out of the data?

Answer (score 0):

@ghoso I'm afraid this question is unclear - the described dict has `Basis` under Soup and `main ingrediants` under Salad, while `cabbage` looks like a brother to `Basis` a complete data structure Salad :)

You can find all possible permutations of an iterable with [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) But for this to work you should define the data structure correctly. Good luck